# Strange issue with routes in Win10

Tags: windows-10, gateway, routing-table

I suffer a very strange issue on Win10.

Laptop is is connected with fritzbox at home (default gateway 192.168.178.1) via wireless LAN. (works)

If I take it to work I connect it via Docingstation with an ethernet cable. default gateway 192.168.x.1 (after boot up it works)

After I suspended and woke up it does not work any more.

I double checked routingtable which was fine. But if I `tracert` somewhere it tries to reach the 192.168.178.1 . But why - and how can I stop it doing it? It's not in Routing Table, wireless is not connected.

Comment: At work, do you restart the computer or wake it up from sleep? Which application is accessing `192.168.178.1`?

Comment: Suspend saves the ipconfig information. When you bring it back up it is trying to use the saved configuration information. Try shutdown each time you move, the problem goes away.

Comment: On some days I restart Computer several times in order to get it working. Sometimes it helps, sometimes it wouldnt